# How do i restrict draggable object movement to an area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have given the user the ability to generate their input onto the screen and also move each character around.

I don't want them to be able to move/place these characters anywhere though, I want to restrict the movement to a small square or rectangle.

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="word-container">
  <div class="character">P</div>
  <div class="character">l</div>
  <div class="character">a</div>
  <div class="character">c</div>
  <div class="character">e</div>
  <div class="character">m</div>
  <div class="character">a</div>
  <div class="character">r</div>
  <div class="character">k</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>

<form action="demo_form">
  Word:
  <input type="text" id="my-word" name="fname">
  <br>
  <button type="button" id="make-word">Make word</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.character {
  width: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: drag;
}
```

JQuery

```
function initDragable($elements) {
  $elements.draggable();
}
initDragable($('.character'));

$(function(){
    $('#make-word').click(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var letters = $('#my-word').val().split('');
      letters = '<div class="character">'+letters.join('</div><div class="character">')+'</div>';
      initDragable($('#word-container').html(letters).find('.character'));
    });
});
```

Comment: using html5 native drap & drop, you may use an attribute https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#the-dropzone-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can specify containment: http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-containment

I believe you can just change your initDraggable function:

```
function initDragable($elements) {
  $elements.draggable({ containment: 'parent' });
}
```

A subsequent request asked about moving the vertical positioning of the characters: you can accomplish this be adjusting the styles for the characters and the character container:

```
.character {
  width: 10px;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline;
  cursor: drag;
}

#word-container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I added a border around the container (so this feature can be easily seen) and added a height of 100px. I then set the line-height of the character to be 100px so it appears in the middle of the #word-container element. The user can now click and drag elements both vertically and horizontally within the #word-container element.

Comment: Thats great, any way i could get it so i could move the character slightly above and below its current position too?